# Does it make a difference whether I put 'friend class xxxxx' in the public or private section?

Tags: c++, private, public, friend

```
class A1 { public: friend class B; }
class A2 { private: friend class B; }
```

Any difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Friend declaration in C++ - difference between public and private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407691/friend-declaration-in-c-difference-between-public-and-private)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, access specificators have no effect on `friend` declaration.