# Friend declaration in C++ - difference between public and private

Tags: c++, private, friend, public

Is there a difference between declaring a friend function/class as private or public? I can't seem to find anything about this online.

I mean the difference between:

```
class A
{
 public: 
      friend class B;
 };
```

and

```
class A
{
 private: //or nothing as the default is private
      friend class B;
 };
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: Such misinformation... someone didn't deserve to be a friend.  It's entirely up to you whether you like your friends tucked in with your privates.

Comment: may i ask what a friend class is :'(?

Comment: @I Phantasm - it's a declaration that allows an instance of the `friend` class to access the members declared `private` in the class that made the declaration.  In the case of this example, an instance of class B can access the private members of class A

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it make a difference whether I put 'friend class xxxxx' in the public or private section?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722222/does-it-make-a-difference-whether-i-put-friend-class-xxxxx-in-the-public-or-pri)

Comment: This question has earned me way too many points on this site.  All right then.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

No, there's no difference - you just tell that class B is a friend of class A and now can access its private and protected members, that's all.

Comment: so I guess whoever told me that just didn't know what they were talking about.  Thanks :)

Comment: but for documentation purposes, would you consider a `friend` an implementation detail or part of the interface?

Comment: @TemplateRex: IMO that's part of interface - it's quite a strong claim that there's some (random) `class Friend` which can access all private members of the current class.

Comment: for random class, yes. But say you implement `operator==(T, T)` using private data members of `T`, and use `friend` as an implementation detail so that `operator==` can appear as a non-member. IMO, this friendship should not appear in the public interface (as will be generated by Doxygen e.g.)

Comment: I read some time ago here in stackoverflow that some compilers, I guess some old buggy ones, will get confused if a friend declaration happens within a non-public region.

Answer (score 44):

Since the syntax `friend class B` doesn't declare  a *member* of the class `A`, so it doesn't matter where you write it, class `B` is a friend of class `A`.

Also, if you write `friend class B` in `protected` section of `A`, then it does NOT mean that `B` can access only `protected` and `public` members of `A`.

Always remember that once `B` becomes a friend of `A`, it can access *any* member of `A`, no matter in which section you write `friend class B`.

Comment: so I guess whoever told me that just didn't know what they were talking about.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

c++ has the notion of 'hidden friends': http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1601r0.pdf

Which only applies to friend functions that are defined inline. This make it so the functions can only be found via argument-dependent lookups, removing them from enclosing namespace.

Answer (score -4):

The friend declaration appears in a class body and grants a function or another class access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration appears.

As such access specifiers have no effect on the meaning of friend declarations (they can appear in private: or in public: sections, with no difference).

Comment: Answering a seven-year-old question without being new. Please take away from making things more duplicated.