# Placement of friend declarations

Tags: c++, class, friend, protected, private-members

Does it matter where in a class a `friend` clause is placed (i.e. within the `protected` block as opposed to the `private` block)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Friend declaration in C++ - difference between public and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407691/friend-declaration-in-c-difference-between-public-and-private)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it does not.

```
class X
{
public:
    friend class A;
private:
    friend class B;
protected:
    friend class C;
};
```

All three classes are now friends of `X` and share the exact same priviliges.

A good convention is to group all friend declarations together for visibility, but that's just style.

#### 11.4 Friends

> 9) A name nominated by a friend declaration shall be accessible in the
>   scope of the class containing the friend declaration. The meaning of
>   the friend declaration is the same whether the friend declaration
>   appears in the `private`, `protected` or `public` (9.2) portion of the class
>   member-specification.

Comment: I'll add a convention of mine which is to put it in the private block as a reminder when looking at it of "who can touch this part"

Comment: @mark: I put it in the `private` part, but at the top of the class (right after the `{`) as a reminder to all readers that some may bypass the public interface hereafter listed.

Comment: I put it in the `public` part since that's often the only part that other devs read.