# Friend function returning (void*): cannot get implementation in .cpp file to work

Tags: c++, gcc, friend, void-pointers

Here is a shortcut of my code:

```
//myClass.h
namespace toto
{
  class myClass
  {
    friend void *myRoutine(void*);
    private:
      char* _name;
  }
}

//myClass.cpp
using namespace toto;
void *myRoutine(void* arg)
{
  myClass* foo = static_cast<myClass*>(arg);
  if ( NULL != foo )
  {
    cout << foo->_name;
  }
}
```

When compiling with GCC, I get an error "_name is private". I absolutly need that signature of function since it is used as a thread routine. And I'd like to avoid changing my attributes to public..

If somebody can help me, thanks !

**Edit:** In addition, myClass is defined in a namespace, and in the .cpp file I put a "using namespace ..." at the beginning.

Comment: Is `myRoutine` not defined in the same namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend declaration in `myClass`, declares a `toto::myRoutine` while your function definition defines a `::myRoutine`. Define `myRoutine` in the same namespace as `myClass` to fix your problem.

Comment: That's it, thanks ! But what surprises me is there is no other error telling me the friend function is not implemented. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Ricola3D it is because you never call the friend function.

Comment: @juanchopanza Oh right since I define two functions and I only call ::myRoutine !

Answer (score 1):

> In addition, myClass is defined in a namespace, and in the .cpp file I put a "using namespace ..." at the beginning.

Don't do that. In the `.cpp` file, you must define the function inside the namespace, like this

```
namespace toto
{
  void* myRoutine(void* arg) { ...}
}
```

or like this

```
void* toto::myRoutine(void* arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

myRoutine() should be written inside the namespace, either by

```
namespace toto
{
// write the function here
}
```

or

```
void *toto::myRoutine( //....
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use get method in your class like ,

```
char* getname()
{
   return _name;
}
```

Than call foo->getname().

Comment: The example I gave you is a very shortcut. This is included in a very huge framework and I would like to avoid any possible public access that other developers could make a wrong use of ^^
Indeed some attributes are aggregated pointers, and thus I need a not-constant pointer to them in my routine. But I don't want anybodyelse to change the pointed object.

Comment: This is the standard method of accessing private members of the class

Comment: I know, it's the standard when you don't need specific privileges for some class or function. Otherwise you need the "friend" keyword

Comment: Tried it, no difference. In addition, after reading it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407691/friend-declaration-in-c-difference-between-public-and-private), It results the friend function/class is really not declared as a member, thus it doesn't take in consideration any private/public/protected key word just before its declaration... Maybe an issue of namespace ? The implementation is considered as a new function and not the implementation of my friend declared function ?

Comment: In any case, this does not answer the question.